# Animation not working reliably (Danmakufu 0.12m)

Tags: c, animation, math

I've had this problem for a week or so and no one has been able to help me with this (not even on the forums that have actual Danmakufu troubleshooting threads and all...). So, the animation of the boss is not working reliably. Sometimes the animation plays and sometimes it doesn't. I think it's something with the if() statements, but I don't know what it is in them. I try to explain some Danmakufu specific stuff to so people not familiar with it (but familiar with C-like programming in general) can help.

**@DrawLoop {}** - This is essential part of the script and all boss related drawing is located here.
**SetTexture, SetRenderState, SetAlpha, SetGraphicScale and SetGraphicAngle** - Various drawing options to define how the boss is drawn.
**GetSpeedX and GetSpeedY** - Get the x and y speed values of the boss (can be negative).
**SetGraphicRect** - Defines the area from the image to display. SetGraphicRect(0, 0, 31, 31); draws a 32x32 area from the top left corner.
**GetAngle** - Get the angle of the boss's movement
**DrawGraphic** - Draws the boss
**GetX and GetY** - Gets the x and y coordinates of the enemy (boss in this case)

Here is a full list of functions if you need it: http://dmf.shrinemaiden.org/wiki/Functions_(0.12m)

NOTE: frame, frame2 and angle are variables defined outside the @DrawLoop {} to make them global.

> ### Script
>
> @DrawLoop {
>
> ```
>   SetTexture(Boss);
>   SetRenderState(ALPHA);
>   SetAlpha(255);
>   SetGraphicScale(1.5, 1.5);
>   SetGraphicAngle(0, 0, 0);
>
>   if(int(GetSpeedX())==0 && int(GetSpeedY())==0) {
>       if(frame<15){ SetGraphicRect(0, 0, 31, 31); }
>       if(frame>=15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 0, 64, 31); }
>       frame++;
>       frame2 = 0;
>   }
>
>   if(angle>=315 && angle<=359) {
>       if(frame2<5){ SetGraphicRect(0, 96, 31, 128); }
>       if(frame2>5 && frame2<10){ SetGraphicRect(32, 96, 63, 128); }
>       if(frame2>10 && frame2<15){ SetGraphicRect(64, 96, 95, 128); }
>       if(frame2>15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 96, 63, 128); }
>       frame = 0;
>       frame2++;
>   }
>
>   if(angle>=0 && angle<=44) {
>       if(frame2<5){ SetGraphicRect(0, 96, 31, 128); }
>       if(frame2>5 && frame2<10){ SetGraphicRect(32, 96, 63, 128); }
>       if(frame2>10 && frame2<15){ SetGraphicRect(64, 96, 95, 128); }
>       if(frame2>15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 96, 63, 128); }
>       frame = 0;
>       frame2++;
>   }
>
>   if(angle>=135 && angle<=224) {
>       if(frame2<5){ SetGraphicRect(0, 64, 31, 96); }
>       if(frame2>5 && frame2<10){ SetGraphicRect(32, 64, 63, 96); }
>       if(frame2>10 && frame2<15){ SetGraphicRect(64, 64, 95, 96); }
>       if(frame2>15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 64, 63, 96); }
>       frame = 0;
>       frame2++;
>   }
>
>   if(angle>=225 && angle<=314) {
>       if(frame2<5){ SetGraphicRect(64, 32, 95, 63); }
>       if(frame2>5 && frame2<10){ SetGraphicRect(32, 32, 63, 63); }
>       if(frame2>10 && frame2<15){ SetGraphicRect(0, 32, 31, 63); }
>       if(frame2>15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 32, 63, 63); }
>       frame = 0;
>       frame2++;
>   }
>
>   if(angle>=45 && angle<=134) {
>       if(frame2<5){ SetGraphicRect(0, 32, 31, 63); }
>       if(frame2>5 && frame2<10){ SetGraphicRect(32, 32, 63, 63); }
>       if(frame2>10 && frame2<15){ SetGraphicRect(64, 32, 95, 63); }
>       if(frame2>15){ SetGraphicRect(32, 32, 63, 63); }
>       frame = 0;
>       frame2++;
>   }
>
>   if(frame >= 30) {
>       frame = 0;
>   }
>
>   if(frame2 >= 20) {
>       frame2 = 0;
>   }
>
>   angle = GetAngle;
>
>   DrawGraphic(GetX, GetY);
> ```
>
> }

Comment: If x,y speed is 0, are you aware that you still do something based on the angle?  It looks to me like all the angle stuff should be in an `else` block off that first `if` statement.

Comment: The idle animation works correctly now. However the walking animations still remain the same. Is it possible to check wether x or y speed is bigger so that it doesn't take the - in count if the value is negative. that might be anther way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there are some things you should note. Firstly, you are not covering the full range of angles, so for certain angles (such as 225, for example), nothing will happen. Secondly, the angles are not normalized. I suggest using angle%360 so that angles greater than 360 will be normalized down to the 0-360 range. This might solve the problem if you have not yet solved it.